# My kivy Xcode project is getting a build error "Operation not Permitted"

Tags: python, ios, xcode, kivy

I receive this error anytime i try to build my kivy xcode app. Please i would appreciate any help. Below is the code. "open /Users/temitayoadefemi/Desktop/kivy-ios/dist/root/python3/lib: Operation not permitted". ill appreciate if anyone could assist me as this is my first kivy xcode project. Thank you

Here is the full error:

```
CpResource /Users/temitayoadefemi/Desktop/kivy-ios/dist/root/python3/lib /Users/temitayoadefemi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/chargie-edqskvsfagirhvaorkvnzwjjcexz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/chargie.app/lib (in target: chargie)
cd /Users/temitayoadefemi/Desktop/kivy-ios/chargie-ios
builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/temitayoadefemi/Desktop/kivy-ios/dist/root/python3/lib /Users/temitayoadefemi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/chargie-edqskvsfagirhvaorkvnzwjjcexz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/chargie.app

error: open /Users/temitayoadefemi/Desktop/kivy-ios/dist/root/python3/lib: Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 0):

I have face this issue but i did this and then i was able to install app in my simulator.

1. Clean your derived data.
2. Reset Content & setting of your simulator.
3. Restart your xcode and simulator.

   Hope this will help you.